# Deducing Fundamental theorem of algebra using using the concept of residue at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The following question was asked in my complex analysis assignment and i was unable to solve it.

> Using the concept of residue at infinity , deduce fundamental theorem of Algbera.

I have studied from textbook Joseph Bak and Newman but I am unable to proceed.

I took a polynomial of n degrees let p(z)  with complex coefficients and I have to prove that it has exactly n roots.

Residue theorem at $\infty$ tell that : If f(z) is analytic i $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ except for isolated singularities at $z_1 ,z_2,...,z_n ,\infty$ . Then the sum of its residues ( including point at $\infty$) is 0.

BuT i am not getting any ideas  how I can use this to prove the fundamental theorem.

Can you please guide?

Comment: Show that $f'/f$ has a non zero residue at infinity for non constant polynomial $f$; conclude that $f$ must have finite zero (with a bit more care you can show that the residue at infinity is minus degree of $f$ while residue at finite zero is multiplicity so deduce that there are degree $f$ zeroes)

Comment: @Conrad Can  you please write a detailed answer. It will really help me. I am unable to fill details from these outlines.